# Smoothness of morphisms and completion of local rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f:X\to S$ be a morphism locally of finite type of locally Noetherian schemes. Let $x\in X$. I wonder if the following is a sufficient condition for $f$ being smooth at $x$.

> there exists $n\geq0$ such that $\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{X,x}\cong\widehat{\mathcal{O}}_{S,f(x)}[[t_1,\cdots,t_n]]$.

This seems quite natural, and I would expect an easy-to-cite reference such as the Stacks Project lemma to affirm it.

---

I refer to [Definition 29.34.1](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01V5) for smoothness of $f:X\to S$ at $x\in X$. It means there are affine open subschemes $x\in\mathrm{Spec}(A)\subseteq X$ and $\mathrm{Spec}(R)\subseteq S$ such that $f(\mathrm{Spec}(A))\subseteq \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ and $R\to A$ is a [smooth ring map](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00T2).

Comment: What do you mean for a morphism to be smooth ‘at a point’?

Comment: @CraniumClamp I have edit up a reference for necessary definitions.

Comment: Ok, so it’s just smoothness in a neighborhood. Do you want an answer or a reference? because I can do the former but not the latter

Comment: @CraniumClamp A direct and short answer would be the best. Besides, I just find [Lemma 15.37.4](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07ED) and [Lemma 15.38.6](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07VH). You can compare them with your ideas.

Comment: I was just thinking of formal smoothness and the links you’re referring to are also steps involved in proving formal smoothness.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Looking forward to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fact that a morphism of finite presentation is smooth iff it is formally smooth, it suffices to check formal smoothness at the point $ x $ and this is easy: If we're given a commutative square as below
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Spec} A @>{}>> X\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\operatorname{Spec} A' @>{}>> S
\end{CD}

with $ A' \rightarrow A $ a square-zero surjection of Artin rings and the horizontal morphisms mapping to points $ x $ and $ s = f(x) $, what is desired is a lift $ \operatorname{Spec} A' \rightarrow X $ making the diagram commute. Because $ A,A' $ are Artin rings, the diagram factors as
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\operatorname{Spec} A @>{}>> \operatorname{Spec} \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} \\
@VVV @VVV\\
\operatorname{Spec} A' @>{}>> \operatorname{Spec} \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}}
\end{CD}
so it's enough to get a lift in this commutative square. Equivalently, we just need to lift the morphism $  \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} \rightarrow A $ of $  \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} $-algebras to a morphism $ \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} \rightarrow A' $ but this is obvious from assumption: since $ \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} \cong \widehat{\mathcal{O}_{S, s}} [[ z_1, \ldots, z_n ]] $, just lift arbitrarily the images of the $ (z_i) $ in $ A $ to $ A' $.

Comment: I am feeling somewhere the formal function theorem is used, so that we can reduce to the case when $A$ is Artinian. Can you point out where should this step be?